# Correct way to represent 3Dimentional data for Keras CNN model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am new to numpy. I have a dataset of 1000 3D structures and every structure has x,y,z coordinates. I am trying to use a CNN model but not able to prepare the correct dataset format for the architecture. Here is my pandas data frame dataset:

```
row_id, xlist, ylist, zlist, target
1, [1,2,3,3], [5,2,6,7], [1,0,4,5], 1
2, [-1,6,4,6], [7,-1,4,1], [2,5,3,5], 1
3, [6,4,-2,-2], [2,-6,6,2], [3,0,7,2], 0
...
n, [5,3,1], [5,3,7], [3,5,3], 1
```

I tried this but it is not what I want

```
np.array([dataset['xlist'],dataset['ylist'],dataset['zlist']])
```

I want to obtain a 3D structure with x * y * z dimentions. How can I create a 3D matrix with dimentions 4 * 4 * 4 (for x, y, and z)

Comment: What are the points representing? So is each structure only 4 Points in a room or should they somehow be connected to create a structure?

Comment: there are more than 4 points, In this example only I added only 4. They represent a 3D protein structure.

Answer (score 1):

keras will probably need a representation with (height, width, depth, channel).

So in your case you could start by creating an empty image like this:

```
empty_image = np.zeros(20, 20, 20, 1)
```

This assumes that your x, y, z range from -10 to 10 with pixel size = 1
So for every single point you can turn the zero into a one:

```
empty_image[x+10, y+10, z+10, 0] += 1
```